# php MySQLi Object-Oriented prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new in php, the below is what I did. The output is 012345, that means `$result= $pre->get_result();` has problem.

P.S. I tried to use int instead of String here `$pre->bind_param('i',$id);`, but it has the same output.

```
<?php                       
require 'Connections/pplcon.php';
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
mysqli_set_charset( $conn, 'utf8');
?> 


<?php

/* activate reporting */
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;


$id="1";

    //Created a template
    echo 0; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Coupon WHERE ActivityID = ?";
    //Create a prepared statement
    echo 1; 
    if($pre = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
        echo 2; 
        $pre->bind_param('s',$id);
        echo 3; 

        echo 4; 
        $pre->execute();
        echo 5; 
        $result= $pre->get_result();
        echo 6; 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo $row['ActivityID'] . "<br>";
                }

        }
    }
    else {
        echo 0; 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Everything fine with the db connection?

Comment: I expect output is 01234561

Comment: yes, db connection is fine for sure, because i use the same connection  for another file, it works fine and shows correct record.

Comment: Have you considered declaring `$id` before you bind? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: You should enable exception-based error reporting. Maybe there is some error you missed: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Comment: Where did you define the variable `$id`?

Comment: Right before `echo 4;` @Akintunde

Comment: No it should be before `bind_param()` .. At the moment it should be undefined

Comment: I update the code, please see the updated. but the output is same 012345 and please kindly adv how to find the error report

Comment: what is your PHP version?

Comment: php version 5.8

Comment: there is no such version. Can you check it again?

Comment: php version 5.6.30